# Export or Download d3.js sunburst / collapsible tree charts as pdf file

Tags: svg, d3.js, pdf-generation, collapsable, sunburst-diagram

I need to download my d3.js collapsible tree chart and sunburst chart as PDF file . 
I tried using jspdf.plugin.svgToPdf plugin but it doesnt work.
Could someone guide me in downloading the charts as pdf ?

My source code for collapsible  tree

```
(function () {
var out$ = typeof exports != 'undefined' && exports || this;
var margin = {
    top : 20,
    right : 120,
    bottom : 20,
    left : 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
duration = 750,
root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
        return [d.y, d.x];
    });

var svg;

out$.treeChart = (function (divTag, jsonData) {
    svg = d3.select(divTag).append("svg")
        .attr("id", "treeChart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json(jsonData, function (error, flare) {

        root = flare;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
});

function update(source) {

    $('#loading' + source.id).hide();
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "logo.png")
    .attr("x", "-8px")
    .attr("y", "-8px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("height", "16px");

    var spinner = nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return "loading" + d.id;
        })
        .style("display", "none")
        .append("xhtml:div")
        .html("<img src=\"loading.GIF\"/>");

    nodeEnter.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        return d.url;
    })
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children || d.children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x : source.x0,
            y : source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source : o,
            target : o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x : source.x,
            y : source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source : o,
            target : o
        });
    })
    .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {

    $('#loading' + d.id).show();

    setTimeout(function () {

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/demo/gateways.json", function (addJson) {

            var childObj = getObjects(addJson, 'name', d.name);

            if (childObj[0].children != null) {

                var len = (childObj[0].children).length;

                function collapse2(k) {
                    if (k.children) {
                        k._children = k.children;
                        k._children.forEach(collapse2);
                        k.children = null;
                    }
                }

                childObj[0].children.forEach(collapse2);

                var newnodes = tree.nodes(childObj[0].children).reverse();

                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = newnodes[0];
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = newnodes[0];
                    d._children = null;
                }

                update(d);
            } else
                $('#loading' + d.id).hide();

        });

        //do something special
    }, 2000);

}

function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
            continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

})();

Comment: So did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

this is the fastest way to download the svg from a webpage: http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/ you can then easily convert the svg to pdf

Comment: thanks for your reply .  I read that crowbar will work fine only in chrome . I want to export the graph as pdf  programmatic-ally . Please guide me with a jquery plugin or code snippet which will help me with the export.

Comment: i have already looked into this example . I want the PDF creation logic at client side and not at server side . Any idea for it ??

Comment: Could you please help me with this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593455/minimap-for-d3-js-collapsible-tree